# In Racket, how to get and set an object's field as if it was a local variable?

Tags: scheme, field, racket, local-variables

I want to do something like this:

```
(define-field-magic color car)
(set! color "green")
(pretty-display color)
```

Instead of this:

```
(set-field! color car "green")
(pretty-display (get-field color car))
```

Answer (score 4):

One solution, adapted from the [The Racket Guide](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/pattern-macros.html#%28part._.Identifier_.Macros%29), is:

```
(define-syntax color
  (syntax-id-rules (set!)
    [(set! color e) (set-field! color car e)]
    [(clock a ...) ((get-field color car) a ...)]
    [clock (get-field color car)]))
```

But there might be better and more readable ways.

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to the question in the title.

The solution below works for public fields. Note that the fields of color% from racket/draw are private. For this reason I have defined my own color% class below:

```
#lang racket

(define color%
  (class object%
    (init-field [r 0]
                [g 0]
                [b 0]
                [a 1.0])
    (super-new)))

(define-syntax-rule (define-local id class-expr field-id object-expr)
  (begin
    (define get (class-field-accessor class-expr field-id))
    (define put! (class-field-mutator class-expr field-id))  
    (define-syntax id
      (syntax-id-rules (set!)
        [(set! id e) (put! object-expr e)]
        [id          (get object-expr)]))))

(define a-color (make-object color% 255 255 255 1.0))
(define-local red   color% r a-color)
(define-local blue  color% g a-color)
(define-local green color% b a-color)

red
(set! red 125)
red
```

The output is:

```
255
125
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do something similar to what you want, without having to use macros, is via [SRFI 17](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-17/srfi-17.html):

```
(require srfi/17)
(define (bind-field field obj)
  (getter-with-setter
   (lambda ()
     (dynamic-get-field field obj))
   (lambda (val)
     (dynamic-set-field! field obj val))))
```

Now, you can do this (I renamed your object from `car` to `obj`, since `car` is a built-in function and you don't want to shadow that):

```
(define color (bind-field 'color obj))
(set! (color) "green")
(pretty-display (color))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Andres' answer - which I upvoted - but possibly a bit more idiomatic:

```
(define-syntax color
  (syntax-id-rules (set!)
   [(set! id e) (set-field! color car e)]
   [(id a ...) ((get-field color car) a ...)]
   [id (get-field color car)]))
```